# Premature End of Script Headers?

Tags: php, session, submit, isset

I have a problem with the code, it is the premature execution error when using `header`.

**Code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php';
$prepend = "<span class='welcome'>";
$append = "</span>";
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
header("Location: login.php");
}
echo $prepend."Здравей ".$_SESSION['name'].$append."</br>";


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$newname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newname']);
$newpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newpass']);
$oldpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['oldpass']);
$checkPass = "SELECT pass from admin WHERE pass = '$_POST[oldpass]'";
$rs = mysqli_query($connect,$checkPass);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
if ($data > 0) 
{
        $query = "UPDATE admin SET pass ='".$_POST['newpass']."',name ='".$_POST['newname']."'" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if ($result === true) 
    {
        echo "Update sucessfuly!";
    }

   }
    else {
    header('Location: admin.php?failed=1');
    }
 }
 ?>
```

The first time when you open the page the `else` part is performed immediately and I can not understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have 2 weird lines in your code:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($connect,$checkPass);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Those function don't exist, in fact you probably used the `mysql_...()` ones, as it seems confirmed by the previous statements.

Now when you execute

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

then `$data` is an array (the next record returned) or FALSE (when no more record exist. And this statement should belong to a loop.

Anyway, in the current form of your code, when you execute `if ($data > 0)`, it can't return anything significative since `$data` is an array.

So you must refactor all this piece of code according to your need (I guess you want to control that `pass` was really found by the previous query).

Answer (score 0):

the first time you open page, the else part is executed because the session variables are not set, you need to set session variables first.

```
$_SESSION['sessionName']= $value;
```

you must have done this on some other page, if so, then please share the code.

and try using

```
if(mysqli_num_row($data)>0)
{

$query = "UPDATE admin SET             
pass='".$_POST['newpass']."',name='".$_POST['newname']."'" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if ($result === true) 
{
    echo "Update sucessfuly!";
}

   }

    else{
    header('Location: admin.php?failed=1');
    }
 }
 ?>
```